# Quando usar "monitoramento" e "monitoração"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Existe um correto e outro errado? Se ambos estão corretos, em quais contextos cada um deles deve ser usados?

Comment: Não é _monitoriamento_?

Comment: Mais um efeito do fato de não haver uma entidade comum para Brasil e Portugal (como ocorre no idioma espanhol) que definisse as novas palavras que fossem surgindo e a sua grafia. Assim Portugal fica com os seus telemóvel, autocarro, comboio, ecrã etc enquanto o Brasil vai por outros caminhos bem diferentes como celular, ônibus, trem, monitor, etc.

Comment: Em Portugal não se usa nenhuma das duas, usa-se sim monitorização do verbo [monitorizar](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/monitorizar).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tanto a palavra "monitoração" quanto "monitoramento" estão relacionadas ao ato de monitorar e podem ser utilizadas a livre escolha, estando elas corretas no ponto de vista morfológico, sendo apenas nominações possíveis do verbo *monitorar*.

Em uma breve pesquisa no Google, descobri que a forma *monitorar* e os seus derivados são mais frequentes no português do Brasil e que a forma *monitorizar* e os seus derivados são mais frequentes no português de Portugal. As pesquisas revelam ainda que o substantivo mais usado no Brasil é *monitoramento* e que o substantivo equivalente mais usado em Portugal é *monitorização*.

Fonte: [Cláudia Pinto, *Dúvida Linguística*, PLiP, 2004.](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/783)

Answer (score 3):

Pra mim, *monitoração* é o ato de monitorar, e *monitoramento* é o efeito de monitorar. Na prática acabo usando mais *monitoração* mesmo. Este artigo, [-cão ou -mento (2015)](https://gramatiquepraque.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/cao-ou-mento/), tem uma boa explicação:

> Muitas pessoas pensam que os sufixos *-ção* e *-mento*, formadores de
>   nomes a partir de verbos, tem o mesmo valor semântico, isto é, o mesmo
>   significado.
>
> [...]
>
> No par de palavras *coroação/ coroamento*, a primeira é utilizada, na
>   maior parte das vezes, com o sentido de “colocação de coroa” (Ex. A
>   coroação do rei), enquanto a segunda ocorre quase que exclusivamente
>   com o sentido de “desfecho” (Ex. A minha promoção na empresa foi o
>   coroamento).
>
> Portanto, *-ção* e *-mento* podem ter seus sentidos aproximados, mas
>   devemos olhar para o contexto de ocorrência e para a intenção de quem
>   utiliza, para entender o funcionamento.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoração e Monitoramento não têm o mesmo significado na língua culta. A primeira é a ação do verbo monitorar enquanto a segunda é o efeito do verbo monitorar. Quando estamos em monitoração, realizamos o monitoramento de algo. É sutil semânticamente, mas distinto. Infelizmente, o ensino da Língua Portuguesa tem perdido muita importância no cenário político dos últimos 20 anos. É a busca pela alienação e manipulação do povo.

Comment: Cursinoprs, bem-vindo ao site. Tens alguma referência em que apoiar a tua afirmação? O dicionário [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/monitoramento) diz que *monitoramento* é o mesmo que *monitoração*. E o Houaiss diz que *monitoramento, monitoração, monitoragem* e *monitorização* são todos a mesma coisa. Para ires contra dois dicionários, é bom que tenhas algo forte em que te apoiares.

Answer (score 0):

É. Na verdade no campo semântico, linguisticamente falando, realmente têm o mesmo significado. No entanto, de repente, vendo dentro de um texto de entidade classista que fazia referência às propostas  em pauta a serem discutidas como reivindicação ao governo estadual,  "
SEGURANÇA NAS ESCOLAS.

Está sendo criado um Plano para monitoração da segurança nas Escolas dentro do aspecto tecnológico..." e me soou estranho. 
   Certamente, só uma impressão minha, mesmo. Talvez, pelo uso mais frquente da palavra " monitoramento". 
Mas, aí está a beleza da nossa Língua.  A riqueza do vocabulário e seus significados.